# My widget doesn't appear on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I develop an app that has a widget that works very well on android pre lollipop, I don't know why but is missing on Android > 5.0 systems. Does anybody has the same problem?

I used:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/widget_height"
    android:minWidth="@dimen/widget_width"
    android:previewImage="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0">

</appwidget-provider>
```

and standard `AppWidgetProvider`

Comment: Tried restarting device? Had faced similar issue before. Restarting did the trick.

Comment: @jitinsharma nope, nothing chaned

Comment: Can you share some code where `RemoteViews` are being created.

Comment: @ jitinsharma, that doesn't metter - it shout show widget without creating any RemoteViews into it...